# How spring boot uses maven, if there is no local repository and no environment variable is set for maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application from spring initializr, which is using maven,java, spring boot 1.5.19, group : com.test , articraft :  userPortal.
After that I have imported that project in my eclipse neon , then maven started to download all maven dependencies but I haven't installed and added maven environment in my system before.
Project is working fine in this system(WINDOWS 10).
But the problem is I have tried the same in other system(WINDOWS 7) where local maven(3.1 version) repository and env variable were set. In that system, I getting many error that I am fixing by modifying setting.xml.

My question is do spring boot automatically install maven and set env variable? Otherwise how it worked in first system.

I have checked my first system where project is running smoothly, and in my c:/users/username/ directory a .m2 and a .p2 dir is get created. In .m2 there is a repository dir, probably maven is using this folder but there is no env variable set by maven. So, How it is working?

I'm new to spring boot and maven, please correct me if anything is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with Spring boot. It's your Eclipse with a configured Maven plugin.

Comment: Dear htn, I'm using same version of eclipse (eclipse neon) in both the system. Which eclipse configuration I need to check and how, can you please suggest.

Comment: Sorry Anup, I have switched from Eclipse to Intellij for many years. Normally, you should find maven configuration somewhere in your Eclipse settings.

Comment: Dear htn, I have checked that in eclipse( windows-> preference -> maven -> user setting) local repository path is mentioned as ${user.home}/.m2/repository, so there in my first system it is creating repository there. But why in second system it is giving error like parent POM is not found. Though second system is correctly pointing to maven setting.xml .

Comment: In my first system I did nothing in setting.xml and it is running smoothly but in case of second one it is giving error. thought in second system I have used a newly maven and default setting.xml and I didn't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot I suggest you better use STS IDE; same interface as Eclipse but Spring Framework friendlier. 
STS already has inbuilt Maven which is different from your locally installed maven and independent. I don't think setting.xml is the issue here. 
If you say error is parent POM not found, try to downgrade the parent version to a lower version supported by the repository and do maven update and build again. 
I hope Eclipse has the same features but try out STS if issue persist.

Comment: Dear Esli, I think you are suggesting a different solution, definitely I will try that out. But my main concern is why there is a error for second system. In my first system mvn is not installed and that is working. So, I have tested the same also in my second system by deleting env variable. Basically I have tried both means with setting mvn env and without mvn env. In both cases I'm getting error. Whereas in my first system nothing is required and project is also working fine. Can you please say why maven is behaving differently in different system?